# knockout - dependent object attributes when managing an array

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have a view model which is basically an array of objects. The object has a StartDate and an EndDate attribute. I am trying to implement a functionality wherein the EndDate of the previous item in the array should be T - 1 of the StartDate of the current item. For eg:

If the array is something like:

```
   Type      Start Date       End Date
   ObjectA   5/1/2014         5/31/2014
   ObjectB   6/1/2014
```

Now, when the user changes the ObjectB's StartDate to lets say 6/15/2014, ObjectA's EndDate should automatically change to 6/14/2014.

How can I achieve this with knockout? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ObjectB start date should be observable. Then subscribe to observable property and when it changes, change property of ObjectA.

```
function addDays(date, value) {
            return new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() + value, date.getHours(), date.getMinutes(), date.getMilliseconds());
        }

ObjectB.StartDate.subscribe(function (newDate){
  ObjectB.EndDate(addDays(newDate, -1));
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, Tomas. I have 2 questions arising out of your solution: 1. Because this is an array, I need to know the array index of the StartDate that got modified, to determine the correct EndDate field to update. How do I get this? & 2. To begin with, I am using ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self); to bind the existing data. How do I add the subscription on those StartDate fields?

Comment: Looks like you best friend would be something similar to linked list. After you finished mapping using fromJS, you need to iterate over all items and add subscriptions. You can add property "previous" to each item so when it changes you have a pointer to previous item. Subscribe function takes second parameter to which "this" will be bound. See example here: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/06/10-things-to-know-about-knockoutjs-on.html

Comment: aweomse!! that worked!! Thank you so much for your help, Tomas. You're the man!! :)